XMLHttpRequest error when trying to run google map project on web
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.0427136,13.7101312&radius=10000&key=A' from origin 'http://localhost:64496' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I am getting this error when i am trying to access the nearby places in web based app, using google map API call. It works fine when i am trying to run the project on Andriod emulator.
I dont know what should i change in order to fix the problem.
I tried creating a proxy server using node and then running it. still i got the same error. When i try to access the direct link in chrome i get the jason file of nearby places but its not displaying in the app
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.get('/api/places', (req, res) => {
  const { lat, lng, radius } = req.query;
  if (!lat || !lng || !radius) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Latitude, longitude, and radius parameters are required' });
  }
  const apiKey = process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY;
  const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${lat},${lng}&key=${apiKey}`;

  request(url, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      res.json(JSON.parse(body));
    } else {
      res.status(response.statusCode).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch data from Google API' });
    }
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));

This is how i am calling the nearby places-
Future<List<dynamic>> getNearbyPlaces(
      double lat, double lng, double radius) async {
    final url =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$lat,$lng&radius=$radius&key=$apiKey';
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final result = json.decode(response.body);
        return result['results'];
      } else {
        print(
            'Failed to load nearby places: ${response.statusCode} - ${response.body}');
        throw Exception('Failed to load nearby places');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error in getNearbyPlaces: $e');
      rethrow;
    }
  }

Future<void> _getCurrentLocation(
      maps_flutter.GoogleMapController controller) async {
    try {
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high); // Get current position
      controller.animateCamera(maps_flutter.CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        maps_flutter.CameraPosition(
          target: maps_flutter.LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
          zoom: 15,
        ),
      ));
      _getNearbyPlaces(
          position.latitude, position.longitude); // Get nearby places
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error getting current location: $e');
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Error getting current location')),
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> _searchLocation(String query) async {
    try {
      final result = await _geocodingService
          .getCoordinates(query); // Get coordinates for query
      if (result != null) {
        final maps_flutter.GoogleMapController controller =
            await _controller.future;
        controller.animateCamera(maps_flutter.CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
          maps_flutter.CameraPosition(
            target: maps_flutter.LatLng(result['lat'], result['lng']),
            zoom: 14.4746,
          ),
        ));
        _getAttractionsInCity(query); // Get attractions in city
        setState(() {
          _searchHistory.add(query);
          _filteredSearchHistory.clear();
        });
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text('Location not found')),
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error searching location: $e');
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Error searching location')),
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> _getNearbyPlaces(double lat, double lng) async {
    try {
      final places = await _placesService.getNearbyPlaces(
          lat, lng, _searchRadius); // Get nearby places
      setState(() {
        _places = places;
        _markers = places
            .map((place) => maps_flutter.Marker(
                  markerId: maps_flutter.MarkerId(place['place_id']),
                  position: maps_flutter.LatLng(
                      place['geometry']['location']['lat'],
                      place['geometry']['location']['lng']),
                  infoWindow: maps_flutter.InfoWindow(
                    title: place['name'],
                    snippet: place['vicinity'],
                  ),
                  icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                      BitmapDescriptor.hueRed),
                ))
            .toList();
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error getting nearby places: $e');
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Error getting nearby places')),
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> _getAttractionsInCity(String city) async {
    try {
      final places = await _placesService
          .getAttractionsInCity(city); // Get attractions in city
      setState(() {
        _places = places;
        _markers = places
            .map((place) => maps_flutter.Marker(
                  markerId: maps_flutter.MarkerId(place['place_id']),
                  position: maps_flutter.LatLng(
                      place['geometry']['location']['lat'],
                      place['geometry']['location']['lng']),
                  infoWindow: maps_flutter.InfoWindow(
                    title: place['name'],
                    snippet: place['formatted_address'],
                  ),
                  icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                      BitmapDescriptor.hueRed),
                ))
            .toList();
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error getting attractions in city: $e');
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Error getting attractions in city')),
      );
    }
  }

This is my code for nearby places and if i search any city in search bar. I failed to get the attraction

The answer here seems to very detailed in helpful.
